# 'stdio.h' file not found

Tags: c, cygwin, stdio

[red arrow shows up upon hover :'stdio.h' file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si25u.png)
[compiles without any errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VguyP.png)
I am pretty new to c (just started).I checked in cygwin directory the files do exist idk why this shows up tho. Should i be worried ? My code compiles and runs like normal.

I did look up the files and they do exist in the right directory but idk[upon searching the directory of cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIfJO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cygwin `include` directory you found is probably not configured as one of the include paths in your editor.

You seem to be using CodeLite, in which case look under:

- Settings
- Project settings
- Compiler
- Include Paths/Additional search paths

The [documentation site](https://docs.codelite.org/workspaces/default/) has screenshots and more options.

Comment: what paths should I include?

Comment: That would be `C:\cygwin64\usr\include` as shown in your screenshot. Add it to whatever is already there.